# MacPorts: is it possible to move /opt/local on a different disk?

Tags: macos, macports

Is there a secure procedure to move the macports directory strucutre on a non-root partition or disk?

Answer (score 4):

**Use a symbolic link...**

A symlink is basically like a file or folder shortcut but it's different in that that it acts as though it **is** the location it's linking to. To the operating system, a symlink and the actual location are no different.

What you'd do is copy the contents of /opt/local to the new location (including hidden files) then, from the /opt/ folder create a symlink.

The format for symlinks is:

```
ln -s target link_name
```

So, the link would be something like:

```
ln -s /new/opt/local/location/ local
```

Since you want to put it on another disk/partition you have to make sure it mounts on boot. If mac doesn't automatically mount the drive/partition in question on boot you'll have to manually edit fstab.

[Here's the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) on symlinks.

[Here's a link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1337628.html) describing how to move the '~/' or 'Home' folder in linux using a symlink. It should work relative the same in OSX since they are both POSIX

[Here's a link](http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=88814) describing how to edit fstab on Mac.

*SideNote: I heart symlinks. They make some things sooooo much easier.*

**Update:**

I forgot one thing. If you want to ensure 'secure' access to the /opt/local folder residing on an external disk. Permissions can be set for the whole disk in fstab. Or, per folder/file via chmod (if the OS supports permissions for that partition type).